# como reutilizar estrutura HTML e mudar conteúdo (evitar o ctrl c ctrl v)

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex:1;
  
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

img{
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <section>
    <h1>Titulo 1</h1>
    <p> alguem paragrafo de descrição 1 </p>

    <ol>
      <li> item 1</li>
      <li> item 2</li>
      <li> item 3</li>
    </ol>
  </section>
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/ae/6f/0c/ae6f0c06031ec9671943bd8be104955f.jpg" width="300px">    
</div>

<div>
  <section>
    <h1>Titulo 2</h1>
    <p> alguem paragrafo de descrição 2 </p>

    <ol>
      <li> aaa </li>
      <li> aaa </li>
      <li> aaa </li>
    </ol>
  </section>
  <img src="https://www.mentebinaria.com.br/uploads/monthly_2018_02/large.enduser.jpeg.bba8c1fc675d79f4498627eef97fef92.jpeg" width="300px">    
</div>

<div>
  <section>
    <h1>Titulo 3</h1>
    <p> alguem paragrafo de descrição 3 </p>

    <ol>
      <li> ronaldo </li>
      <li> romero brito </li>
      <li> kugo stozo </li>
    </ol>
  </section>
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR21uPpWezBvq5pq8wBWN3led17DmF0YTIKsUraGaxbaFyUah8d" width="300px">    
</div>

<div>
  <section>
    <h1>Titulo 4</h1>
    <p> alguem paragrafo de descrição 4 </p>

    <ol>
      <li> amarelo </li>
      <li> azul </li>
      <li> vermelho </li>
    </ol>
  </section>
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ3B6n6DyBqzVZeKgMgceAkL7aoosSLgI6NYG4djCFjKSnxJRWlBA" width="300px">  
</div>
```

primeiramente me desculpe a pergunta de newbie mas eu realmente nao encontrei uma resposta satisfatoria no sr. google.

então, tenho um trecho de codigo que tem 4 divs que seguem o mesmo padrão, mas com conteúdo diferente, como reutilizar esse mesma estrutura e adcionar mais 4 divs,sem usar um (ctrl c ctrl v), o objetivo aqui e diminui a quantidades de linhas no arquivo html.

Comment: Queres fazer isso no browser ou no servidor?

Comment: qual a diferença? acho q no browser.

Comment: Sugiro que faças onde tens o conteúdo para essas divs. Se tens na base de dados parece-me mais lógico no servidor, mas depende da utilização... há prós e contras... que linguagem tens no servidor? onde tens esses dados?

Comment: `<template>` + `json` = . Qualquer coisa posso postar um exemplo baseado na estrutura postada.

Comment: sergio, no momento só no meu computador, estou estudando.

Comment: @ValdeirPsr se nao for dar trabalho irmao, posta ai :)

Comment: O exemplo do @Sergio já ajuda. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Organiza esse conteúdo numa array de objetos. Algo assim:

```js
[{
  titulo: 'Jogadores',
  descricao: 'Os melhores jogadores do mundo',
  items: ['Ronaldo', 'Messi']
},
{
  titulo: 'Cores',
  descricao: 'Cores intressantes',
  items: ['Azul', 'Amarelo']
}]
```

E depois podes ter um pedaço de HTML como "forma" para gerar o HTML com JavaScript:

```js
const conteudo = [{
    titulo: 'Jogadores',
    descricao: 'Os melhores jogadores do mundo',
    items: ['Ronaldo', 'Messi'],
    img: 'https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/grupo-de-summer-games-icon-do-atleta-do-jogador-de-futebol-atleta-isom%C3%A9trico-do-jogador-de-futebol-d-olympics-que-ostentam-73533395.jpg'
  },
  {
    titulo: 'Cores',
    descricao: 'Cores intressantes',
    items: ['Azul', 'Amarelo'],
    img: 'https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/office-2-9/48/81-512.png'
  }
];

const template = document.querySelector('template');

conteudo.forEach(obj => {
  const clone = document.importNode(template.content, true);
  clone.querySelector('h1').textContent = obj.titulo;
  clone.querySelector('p').textContent = obj.descricao;
  clone.querySelector('ol').innerHTML = obj.items.map(item => `<li>${item}</li>`);
  clone.querySelector('img').src = obj.img;
  document.body.appendChild(clone);

});
```

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <section>
      <h1></h1>
      <p></p>
      <ol></ol>
    </section>
    <img src="" width="300px">    
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Questão**:

> 1. **Otimização na escrita de código no Front-end:**
>      
>     Sendo esse o problema, a melhor solução é você usar um **template engine**, permitindo o uso de um arquivo estático - leia-se template, o qual você pode substituir "dinamicamente" valores de variáveis definidas em seu template.
>    Existe varios **templates engines** no mercado, entre eles posso citar os mais conhecidos: **Pug**, **Handlebars**, **Mustache**.
> 2. **Tratar dados dinâmicos do Back-end**
>      
>    Nesse cenário você faz uso de uma linguagem dinâmica que trata esses dados do lado **Server-side** e entrega o conteúdo em texto para browser. Hoje você já pode contar com JavaScript para esse tipo de trabalho, usando **Node** e algum módulo de Server como **Express**, que consegue tratar as requisições e resposta de forma eficiente.
>      O interessante é que você pode trabalhar com um **template engine** nesse cenário também, sendo assim o que antes só era possível fazer com linguagens como PHP e outras, como:
>
>    - **Manipular dados vindo do banco de dados**
>    - **Gerar loops de iteração sobre esse dados de forma dinâmica**
>    - **Tratar esses dados, como realizar algum cálculo por exemplo**
>
> Em suma otimização ou tratar dados dinâmicos, o importante é entender os cenários e saber de fato o que se pretende fazer.

CodePen: [Deixei um exemplo de código usando template engine aqui](https://codepen.io/cheenZhen/pen/yLBpGzL)

**Code snippet**

**Obs**: Atente-se que ao executar o código abaixo, o interpretador não parsea código usando sintaxe de **template engine**, no caso o **Pug**. No entanto isso se trata de um **código dinâmico no Front-end**

```html
- const thinkers = [{name:'carl gustav jung', field:'psychiatry', work:['the archetypes and the collective unconscious','on the nature of the psyche',''], thought:'Tudo que nos irrita nos outros pode nos levar a um melhor conhecimento de nós mesmos.'},{name:'aristóteles', field:'philosopher', work:['de Interpretatione','analytica Priora','de sophisticis elenchis'], thought:'Sábio é aquele que conhece os limites da sua própria ignorância.'}]
- const musicians = [{name:'john Coltrane', style:'jazz', discography:['blue train','soultrane','a love supreme'], bio:'Biography...'},{name:'miles davis', style:'jazz', discography:['tutu','in a silent way','miles ahead'], bio:'Biography...'}]
section.bl-content
  each data,ind in thinkers
    article.bc-featured
      h2.bc-featured__title= data.name
      p.bc-featured__paragraph= data.thought
      ul.bc-featured__list
        each item,ind in data.work
          li.bc-featured__item= item
section.bl-content          
    each data,ind in musicians
      article.bc-featured
        h2.bc-featured__title= data.name
        p.bc-featured__paragraph= data.bio
        ul.bc-featured__list
          each item,ind in data.discography
            li.bc-featured__item= item
```